# How can I give HyperLink in my full calender?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, eloquent, fullcalendar

I am displaying my events in calender. It will display it properly. But I want that when I click on that event it will redirect on particular event_detail page.

I am beginner in laravel so woll you please help me???

This Is my controller file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Carbon;
use Calendar;
use App\Event;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CalendarController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /*
    *Display All The Events In Calendar
    *
    */
    public function calendar()
    {
        $event = [];
        $allEvent = Event::all();

        if($allEvent->count())
        {
            foreach ($allEvent as $key => $eventList) 
            {
                $event[] = Calendar::event(
                    $eventList->name,
                    true,
                    new \DateTime($eventList->event_date),
                    new \DateTime($eventList->evet_date)
                );
            }
        }
        $showInCalendar = Calendar::addEvents($event);
        return view('admin.calendar.event_calendar', compact('showInCalendar', 'allEvent'));
    }
}
```

This is muy blade file

```
@extends('admin.layout.default')

@section('css')
<link href="{{ url('assets/plugins/calendar/dist/fullcalendar.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
@endsection

@section('content')

<div class="row page-titles">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-8 align-self-center">
        <h3 class="text-themecolor">Calendar</h3>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Calendar</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card card-outline-info">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div id="calendar">                            

                            {!! $showInCalendar->calendar() !!}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('jsPostApp')
{!! $showInCalendar->script() !!}
<script src="{{ url('assets/plugins/calendar/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('assets/plugins/moment/moment.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('assets/plugins/calendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
@endsection
```

I dont know how to handle that hyperlink to open that particular event's detils page.

Comment: just set the `url` property for each of your events. See the fullCalendar "event object" documentation for details.

Comment: I know have to set URL property, but I don't know how, will you please help how to write in code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Owk I got the solution

```
public function calendar()
    {
        $event = [];
        $allEvent = Event::all();

        if($allEvent->count())
        {
            foreach ($allEvent as $key => $eventList) 
            {
                $event[] = Calendar::event(
                    $eventList->name,
                    true,
                    new \DateTime($eventList->event_date),
                    new \DateTime($eventList->event_date),
                    null,
                    [
                        'url' => 'event/' .$eventList->id,
                    ]

                );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to achieve that behavior.

You will need to set the property [url](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) in your event objects. Once you have it, you can use the callback [eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick) to redirect the user. By default, `eventClick` will always redirect to link inside `url`.

If you want to display it in a different tab, or a popup, take a look at the section **Cancelling Default Behavior** in the eventClick link I posted here.

Comment: I know have to set URL property, but I don't know how, will you please help how to write in code???